# Same click event two different results?

Tags: jquery

I have a click event lets take this example:

```
$('p').click( function() {
    $('.xclass').css( { 'background' : 'green' } );
});
```

The above code will change the background color of a div if I click the p tag.

Now my question is again clicking the same p tag I want to change the color to yellow!!. How can I do this?.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: @j08691 is also implying that you change the background by adding and removing a class that has css (on the class) that sets the background color. That is in contrast to what you did that directly fools with the `style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clicked_once = false;

$('p').click( function() {
    $('.xclass').css( { 'background' : 'green' } );
    if ( clicked_once ) $('.xclass').css('color', 'yellow');
    clicked_once = true;
});
```

Change a variable after the first click, to know that you've clicked it once before. I prefer using data() over globals, but variables demonstrates it better.

Comment: This method is pretty good. whether we use class or inline style, this will work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$('p').click( function() {
    var color = $('.xclass').css('background-color');
    if(color=='green')
        $('.xclass').css( { 'background' : 'yellow' } );
    else
        $('.xclass').css( { 'background' : 'green' } );
});
```

Comment: i think it comes back as `rgb(0, 128, 0)` and not green http://jsfiddle.net/FE5fM/

Answer (score 0):

you could do it by using classes, which would probably be a better approach.

```
$('p').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('green')){
        $(this).removeClass('green');
        $(this).addClass('yellow');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('green');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like Below...

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/95/

**HTML:**

```
<p>Click</p>
<div class="xclass">hiasg sdnhfg sdfg</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.green
{
    background:green;
}
.yellow
{
    background:yellow;

}
```

**JQuery :**

```
    $('p').click( function() {

    if($('.xclass').hasClass("green"))
    {
      $('.xclass').removeClass("green");
      $('.xclass').addClass("yellow");
    }
    else
    {
        $('.xclass').removeClass("yellow");
        $('.xclass').addClass("green");    
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works checked with jsFiddle...

```
$('p').click( function() {
    if($(".xclass").css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 128, 0)")
    {
        $('.xclass').css( { 'background-color' : 'yellow' } );
    }
    else
    {
        $('.xclass').css( { 'background-color' : 'green' } );
    }
});
```